# Using R plumber for web API over HTTPS

Tags: r, security, web, https, plumber

I am trying to use Plumber in R to expose a model through web API. I want the API calls to be secure over https. I tried to find information on implementing secure API using plumber but unfortunately haven't found anything. 
Does anyone has experience of dong that? Or any other solutions to expose a R model over secure API?

Answer (score 4):

See https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html for a few different options. DigitalOcean and RStudio Connect would both support this.

Comment: Been a few months; just wondering if there are any more options besides DigitalOcean and RStudio Connect. In particular, is there any material showing how to use HTTPS via Docker?